# How to ignore a custom field value if its empty

Tags: wordpress, custom-fields

I have five custom fields for loading images but all of them are not required. I mean the user can upload a random number of images from 1 to 5. I am  stuck in a simple lack of concept here. How should I check if any of them is empty and discard it. More specifically I want to discard the non-existing fields and store only the uploaded ones in an array. Here is my code

```
$custom_fields = get_post_custom($id);

$my_custom_field1 = $custom_fields['image1'];
$my_custom_field2 = $custom_fields['image2']; 
$my_custom_field3 = $custom_fields['image3'];
$my_custom_field4 = $custom_fields['image4'];
$my_custom_field5 = $custom_fields['image5'];

if(!(false===($my_custom_field1))) { $img[]=$my_custom_field1;}
if(!(false===($my_custom_field2))) { $img[]=$my_custom_field2;}
if(!(false===($my_custom_field3))) { $img[]=$my_custom_field3;}
if(!(false===($my_custom_field4))) { $img[]=$my_custom_field4;}
if(!(false===($my_custom_field5))) { $img[]=$my_custom_field5;}
```

Comment: I want to avoid the empty entries.

Answer (score 1):

```
$images = Array("image1","image2","image3","image4","image5");
foreach($images as $image){
    if(isset($custom_fields[$image])){
    $img[] = $custom_fields[$image];
    }
}
```

Didn't tested that, but should work.

Comment: I think that this must work, (excluding the isset stuff as they wont work in CFs) but unfortunately its not working, the blanks are still entering into the array.

Comment: @Lamia Mehreen, then you can try to update if statement next way: if(isset($custom_fields[$image]) && !empty($custom_fields[$image]))

Comment: http://phpfiddle.org/main/code/sf3-0bt could u please check my approach? is there anything stupid going on other than this?

Comment: could you provide var_dump() of $custom_fields ?

Comment: sure here it is https://docs.google.com/document/d/1DEtnldKusmwHhiNjPA81eSFCqoKW7qQOz6xG_uqR4Kk/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: Ah, now it looks more clear:) Look for example at line ["image1"]=> array(1) { [0]=> string(3) "374" }. Statement array(1) means that you have array data type so empty() method willn't work wtith it. The shortest way to handle it is this: if(isset($custom_fields[$image][0]) && !empty($custom_fields[$image][0])){
    $img[] = $custom_fields[$image][0];
    }

Answer (score 0):

```
if(isset($my_custom_field5)){
  // do something with $my_custom_field5
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest using

```
if ( !empty($my_custom_field)){ 
    \\Do Something 
}
```

because isset only checks for variable beings set and not null where as empty checks if the variable is an empty string, false, array(), NULL, “0?, 0, and an unset variable.

Comment: http://phpfiddle.org/main/code/sf3-0bt I'm trying everything but maybe my approach is wrong, please check

Comment: I modified the code and it works in theory. One problem could be that you are using a local $post variable. You may have to declare it as global $post; as $post is set by wordpress core.